# Can I have too much RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory

My current laptop just died & I need  new one.

It had 32gB RAM and regularly used 14 gB. I only occasionally saw it even go over 16gB (maybe once every few weeks).

I am going to buy a new one & want it to last 5 years or so.

Would there be anything at all to gain from 64gB RAM? Or even 32gB again?

All that I can think of would be some, as yet unknown to me, Windows 10 tweaks to load more programs or parts of the o/s into RAM.

What you think? Main use is coding - an IDE or two, a localhost Apache server & a MySql database.

Any benefit of 64gB RAM, or would I just be throwing my money away?

---

[Update] [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/4r8t3n/can_you_have_too_much_ram/) says that I would be throwing my money away. Unless, I guess someone knows how I can make more use of RAM than is done by default on Windows 10 (perhaps anew question?)

[Related](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1470193) ArsTachina forum question, which reminds me:

> Too much RAM can be a problem if your boot drive is small because your hiberfil.sys and swap files will be larger. Hibernation file will be the same size as your RAM

Comment: Why the close vote? As usual, no explanation given. I don't mind close votes, if you tell me what I did wrong, which can help me to make this a better site for all. Close votes with no reason given help no one.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it's because there's too little information to give a meaningful answer. 'An IDE or two, apache, a database', doesn't say anything about the actual memory usages of those applications. Personally I feel there's no such thing as 'too much ram' ;-) I'm currently at 37% of 32GB with just 1 IDE, 1 browser (7 tabs), Outlook and some misc tools. Often I use much more than that. BTW, you can change the size of the swap file manually, and disable hibernation to get rid of hiberfil.sys.

Comment: Thanks (+1). Would, with your usage, go for 64gB "just in case", for that rare occasional? Or just leave it to the Page File? Alas, I prefer to enable Hibernate, but, since I am aiming at 2 @ 2tB SSD, that prolly won't be a problem. I think that I would prefer a generic answer, rather than one tailored to my personal use.

Comment: 64? No, maybe in a couple of years, I got an upgrade from 16 to 32 just a month ago :-) because I regularly hit that limit. If your current 'normal' usage is ~14, I wouldn't recommend 16, unless you are on a tight budget. And if you buy 32 now, consider getting 1×32, rather than 2×16, so it will be easier to get an additional 32, if you need it later (depending on the number of slots available in your new laptop of course)

Comment: Oh, and it seems in recent versions of windows 10, hiberfil.sys can be shrunk to ~40% of the amount of ram. https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reduce-hibernate-file-size-in-windows-7

Comment: Presumably if you're looking at 64GB RAM you're not also considering a 128GB SSD, so the potential extra 32GB of hyberfil will make no practical difference to a 1TB or larger drive; it might take a couple of seconds longer to load up, but I don't really see that as an issue. Once you have the RAM, you'll see it gets used. I've 64GB, of which 50GB is currently "in use", my swap therefore is currently still 0 bytes, even after 18 days' uptime.

Comment: Wow !!  What do you do to use 50 gB?  (Btw, I have taken your advice & gone for the 64 gB, so I will soon know ;-)

Comment: Mainly photoshop - thing is, if I didn't have 64GB RAM, some of that would probably have been reclaimed already. Modern OSes & apps don't hand back memory when they don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information in your post, it seems to me that the performance of your system is not currently limited by memory, so I don't think you will see any immediate benefits from upgrading to 64GB RAM.

However, every project is different. Some projects are very memory-intensive, and especially if you need to run multiple virtual machines or process big datasets etc. memory usage can exceed 32GB. At the time, there are not a lot of projects like that, but you can never know what your next project will be.

The final decision is a trade-off between cost and benefit. If you are a developer, and if this is your primary working machine, and if all other parts are designed to last for 5 or more years (i.e. 8-core CPU, fast SSD etc.) then you might want to protect your investment - aka "futureproofing". Extra 32GB RAM is typically not prohibitly expensive (compared to total cost of such computer). Still, you first need to check if your motherboard supports it (read the specs about maximum supported memory size and check how many free slots it has). If you have a free slot you can always get another 32GB stick later, all you need to do is to make sure the memory type and timings match.

Comment: +1, good answer. I'd just add that with two sticks you get some extra performance from dual channel.